# Can c define a data type in a way that modula-2 defines `TNumber = [minValue,maxValue]`?

Tags: c, types

I would like to define a fixed range that a number-variable can belong to.. I'm using a c89 compiler.
So, if I do:

`#define minValue -200`

`#define maxValue 200`

I would like something on the lines of:
`typedef int range[minValue,maxValue]`

Can something like this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible.
You must add some code to check that your value is in the defined range.

For example

```
typedef int Range; // must be between minValue and maxValue
#define CheckRange(x) (((x)>=minValue) && ((x)<=maxValue))
[...]
Range a = ...; // a call to a function or user input request
if (!CheckRange(a)) 
  // handle error
```

Comment: Ok, I'll believe you. Thanks